# Get every combination of objects from multiple List<> but with unique constraint

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm looking to get every combination of objects from each collection in a set of `List<ObjectName>`s. `ObjectName` will always be the same object, but I can have a varying number of these lists. However, out of all the lists, I need to limit the combinations to only have 1 object with a specific property value, something like `bool Unqiue = true;` or something.

A quick example to demonstrate what I mean, say I have a custom object `MyObj`:

```
class MyObj
{
    public int Value;
    public bool Unique;
}
```

and have 3 `List<MyObj>` collections:

```
MyObj obj1 = new MyObj
{
    Value = 1,
    Unique = false
};

MyObj obj2 = new MyObj
{
    Value = 2,
    Unique = true
};

MyObj obj3 = new MyObj
{
    Value = 3,
    Unique = true
};

MyObj obj4 = new MyObj
{
    Value = 4,
    Unique = false
};

MyObj obj5 = new MyObj
{
    Value = 5,
    Unique = false
};

MyObj obj6 = new MyObj
{
    Value = 6,
    Unique = false
};

List<MyObj> objs12 = new List<MyObj> { obj1, obj2 };
List<MyObj> objs34 = new List<MyObj> { obj3, obj4 };
List<MyObj> objs56 = new List<MyObj> { obj5, obj6 };
```

Say I want each combo as an array, one from each `List<MyObj>`, an example being:

```
MyObj[3] objCombos = new MyObj[] { obj1, obj3, obj5 };
```

I want to get an array like above for every possible combination from the 3 collections. However, if `Unique = true`, I want there to only 1 of those objects in any array. So an array of `obj2, obj3, obj5` would not be valid, because both `obj2` and `obj3` have `Unqiue = true;`.

My original thought was to just iterate through each collection and create all combinations, then loop through those and toss out any that have multiple `Unique = true` objects, but that seems like a waste of time and resources to do it that way:

```
List<MyObj[]> objCombos = new List<MyObj[]>();

//pseudo code: loop through 3 lists and add all combos to objCombos here

int i = 0;
foreach (MyObj[] objArr in objCombos)
{
    if (objArr[0].Unique && objArr[1].Unique && objArr[2].Unique)
        objCombos.RemoveAt(i);

    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

class MyObj
{
    public int Value;
    public bool Unique;
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyObj obj1 = new MyObj{Value = 1, Unique = false};
        MyObj obj2 = new MyObj{Value = 2, Unique = true};
        MyObj obj3 = new MyObj{Value = 3, Unique = true};
        MyObj obj4 = new MyObj{Value = 4, Unique = false};
        MyObj obj5 = new MyObj{Value = 5, Unique = false};
        MyObj obj6 = new MyObj{Value = 6, Unique = false};
        List<MyObj> objs12 = new List<MyObj>{obj1, obj2};
        List<MyObj> objs34 = new List<MyObj>{obj3, obj4};
        List<MyObj> objs56 = new List<MyObj>{obj5, obj6};
        List<List<MyObj>> objLists = new List<List<MyObj>>{objs12, objs34, objs56};
        List<MyObj[]> objCombos = GetUniqueCombos(objLists);
        foreach (MyObj[] objArr in objCombos)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", objArr.Select(x => x.Value)));
        }
    }

    static List<MyObj[]> GetUniqueCombos(List<List<MyObj>> objLists)
    {
        List<MyObj[]> combos = new List<MyObj[]>();
        GenerateCombos(0, objLists, new MyObj[objLists.Count], combos);
        return combos;
    }

    static void GenerateCombos(int listIndex, List<List<MyObj>> objLists, MyObj[] currentCombo, List<MyObj[]> combos)
    {
        if (listIndex == objLists.Count)
        {
            if (currentCombo.Count(y => y != null && y.Unique ) <= 1)
            {
                combos.Add(currentCombo.ToArray());
            }
            return;
        }

        foreach (MyObj obj in objLists[listIndex])
        {
            var newCombo = (MyObj[])currentCombo.Clone();
            newCombo[listIndex] = obj;
            GenerateCombos(listIndex + 1, objLists, newCombo, combos);
        }
    }
}
```

Which produces:

```
1,3,5
1,3,6
1,4,5
1,4,6
2,4,5
2,4,6
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/tD9mWd